# Hits more than total requests

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, akka-http, wrk

So I started learning Scala and Akka actors, Akka-Http. I tried to implement a simple hits counter using Akka Http which counts every hit on the localhost page. I used wrk tool to run 10 threads with 100 connections, after which there is a mismatch between the count and the total requests(Seen on wrk).

This is my code :

```
object WebServer3 {

  var number: Int = 0


  final case class Inc()
  class ActorClass extends Actor with ActorLogging {

    def receive = {
      case Inc => number = number + 1
    }
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[ActorClass], "SimpleActor")
    val route =
      path("Counter") {

        get {
          actor1 ! Inc
         complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, s"<h1>You visited $number times</h1>"))
        }
      }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
  }
}
```

Pardon my immature/amateurish coding skills. I am still learning and I know this has to do with concurrency. But I cannot find a solution yet. Please help.

edit#1 : I tried AtomicInteger too. That did not help. 
edit#2 : I tried the complete akka-http way with ask and await too. that did not help either.

Comment: What do you mean by " there is a mismatch between the count and the total requests" ? How big was the mismatch ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh
Hits on the browser(count) - 164500, Requests/sec for 10 sec - 164390
So around a 100 more than the actual requests

Comment: this number `164390` is the number of requests `sent AND completed` within 10 seconds. It does not count the requests which were just `sent`. A portion of requests which were sent out towards the very end will not be completed before the cutoff and `wrk` will just ignore them and not count them as completed.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh understood! :D Thank you. Also, Is there any way to mirror the same? Requests and count?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I mean, updating/incrementing the counter only after a thread finishes its execution. Is that possible? Thankyou Sarvesh!

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh please help. you are the only person who has replied. online resources does not help either.

Comment: The problem here is with `wrk`. Which sends `x` requests but counts only the requests `y` which completed within the fixed time. Why do you even want to match both counts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems with your code.

You're defining a case class `final case class Inc()` but you're sending a companion object `actor1 ! Inc`. Though, you still match companion object `case Inc =>` and your code works. But it's should not be done this way.

Other problem, we're storing and modifying and retrieving `var number: Int = 0` outside of actor boundaries. And I think this is why you have miscounts. Actor must change only internal state.

I modified your code by introducing [ask pattern](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#ask-send-and-receive-future) so a value can be retrieved from within an actor.

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.{ContentTypes, HttpEntity}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.io.StdIn

object WebServer3 {


  final case object IncAndGet //not a case class anymore

  class ActorClass extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    private var number: Int = 0 //inner state must be private and not accessible from outside of an actor

    def receive = {
      case IncAndGet =>
        number += 1
        context.sender() ! number // send current value back to sender
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
    implicit val timeout: Timeout = 2.seconds

    val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[ActorClass], "SimpleActor")
    val route =
      path("counter") {
        get {
          onComplete((actor1 ? IncAndGet).mapTo[Int]) { number =>
            complete(
              HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
                         s"<h1>You visited $number times</h1>"))
          }
        }
      }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    val _ = bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ivan! But the mismatch in count is still present :( But i really appreciate your help!

Comment: @ashishjohn It does not match indeed. I did a test on with latest version of wrk and it underreports the total amount of requests done already in the case of one thread and two connections. The "problem" is most probably with wrk tool and how it counts requests.